# Can I modify a git commit after it has been merged? fixup does not seem to work well

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I tried to go over this tutorial which shows how to fix a commit with fixup. However it looks it can be done but BEFORE it has been merged in the repository.

https://fle.github.io/git-tip-keep-your-branch-clean-with-fixup-and-autosquash.html

Is it possible to do the same with a commit that is already merged into the main line? I tried the exact steps mentioned above but not only it did not work well, but also doubled the number of commits because there were conflicts. See more or less the problem:

I added five commits and merged them all. Then I wanted to fix "commit 1!" but still have a clean history at the end (only five commits in my case)

step1: created dummy commits

```
$ git log --oneline
e182f6f (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) commit 4!!!
575c99b commit 3~~
f2f3948 commit 2
66dc21d Commit 1!
204a092 Initial commit
```

step2) Modified the file in "Commit 1!" added a fixup commit to fix "Commit 1!"

```
        modified:   file1.txt

$ git add .
$ git commit --fixup 66dc21d
[main dfbc6e9] fixup! Commit 1!
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git log --oneline
dfbc6e9 (HEAD -> main) fixup! Commit 1!
e182f6f (origin/main, origin/HEAD) commit 4!!!
575c99b commit 3~~
f2f3948 commit 2
66dc21d Commit 1!
204a092 Initial commit
```

step3: Rebase with autosquash and there I edited the generated file to choose (pick, squash, fixup, etcc..) I selected the proper choices to to squash the fixup commit(dfbc6e9) with the original commit (66dc21d). So far looked good and I had a clean history with 5 changes only:

```
$ git rebase -i --autosquash 204a092
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/main.


$ git log --oneline
b97d4b7 (HEAD -> main) commit 4!!!
2056bf3 commit 3~~
74c18d4 commit 2
cabb5bb Commit 1!
204a092 Initial commit
```

But then it went down hill from here. when I tired to push and failed since it said the tree was behind.

```
$ git push
To https://bitbucket.org/gmmo/test.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/gmmo/test.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I had to do a pull and rebase again, but when I pushed the result was much worse than if did not "fixup" anything. It doubled the number of commits :(

```
$ git log --oneline
b12075d (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) Merge branch 'main' of https://bitbucket.org/gmmo/test
b97d4b7 commit 4!!!
2056bf3 commit 3~~
74c18d4 commit 2
cabb5bb Commit 1!
e182f6f commit 4!!!
575c99b commit 3~~
f2f3948 commit 2
66dc21d Commit 1!
204a092 Initial commit
```

Is it possible to fix an earlier commit that has been *merged* without messing everything up? If so, how?

thank you very much.

Comment: *Is it possible to fix an earlier commit that has been merged without messing everything up? If so, how?* yes but you have to force push

Comment: "It doubled the number of commits" Of course. Rebase makes _copies_ so now you have two copies of all the rebased commits. But if you _graph_ the history rather than just _listing_ your commits, you will see that things are not in fact particularly messy. Just say `git log --oneline --graph --decorate main` to see how things really stand.

Comment: Also perhaps I'm not being very observant but I don't see where anything is actually merged. You appear to have only one branch, `main`, so what is to merge?

Comment: Paolo gave me answer I was looking for. I had to do a force: 'git push origin master --force'  I omitted few intermediate steps in order to make this post not too long. @matt that might be what you aren't seeing. I never really done fixups, I was a bit lost. But thx you guys for the help.

Comment: If the problem is solved (whatever it was), could you delete the question so as not to leave it hanging? Or you could answer your own question if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

In order the push you need to force the push which was not showed in the article above.

```
git push origin master --force
```

I don't know why people put -1 on this question. This a legitimate question which a final important step omitted in the article above.